# datamapper: account has 1 venue OR has 1 artist

Tags: ruby, associations, datamapper

Okay. I'm new to DataMapper. I've been trying to read through the documentation and understand it in relevance to what I'm trying to accomplish for hours but it's hell for a person with ADD like mine. Google hasn't helped out too much - that said, I'm not exactly sure how to compound my problem into query format. So I'm asking this question in hopes of getting an answer and being able to move on with my project, but I also obsessively want to wrap my head around this. So.

All users that sign up get an Account. The Account has a username, email, and password field, basic stuff. The model itself, ie those properties, work fine (I understand that much).

But depending on how the user identifies, they are also either an Artist, Venue, or Fan. Due to the drastic differences in these identifications, each has its own model. So when a user gets an Account, he also needs to be inserted into either an Artist, Venue, or Fan model. A user cannot be two of these, only one.

My question is how to set up that type of association. I was thinking `has 1, :artist OR has 1, :venue OR has 1, :fan`, but I don't think that's supported. But you get the idea.

I also thought, okay, f*** it, I'll just give an Account `n` Artists and `n` Venues and `n` Fans, but only insert one record to the relevant model. But that seems like a bad, bloated workaround.

Is there a proper way to do this, or at least a best way? Thank you in advance, I hope I explained myself well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user can have either an artist, venue, or fan model associated with it, so you would want something like:

```
class User
  # ...
  has 1, :artist
  has 1, :venue
  has 1, :fan
  # ...
end
```

Next, your user can only be associated with at most one of artist, venue, or fan, so you would want some additional validations on those models:

```
class Artist
  belongs_to :user
  validates_with_method :user_has_no_venue_or_fan
  def user_has_no_venue_or_fan
    if user.fan || user.venue
      [false, "Your custom error message..."]
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

and you would have similar validations for your `Fan` and `Venue` models.

In this way your user class could be associated with a venue, fan, or artist model, but the validations on those models would ensure that the user is not associated with more than one of them.

If you wanted to access your identifying model easily through that user, you could then write a method in user like so:

```
class User
  def placeholder_method_name
    artist || venue || fan
  end
end
```

Comment: ah. i'd considered the has 1 for each model method but didn't pursue it given it wouldn't ensure 1 and only 1 the way i conceived it. your validation line secures that. thank you!

Comment: i actually stumbled upon further problems. here's the new guy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851775/trouble-linking-one-to-one-models-in-datamapper